# Fastest way to chain multiple indexing operations for lists?

Tags: python, performance, list, iteration

I want to classify some data I have and for that to work I want to chain indexing of python lists. Simplified I have a nested list:

```
lst = [[[1], [2]], [[3, 3], [4]], [[5], [6,6,6]]]
```

and I want to iterate over the product of the first two indices but keep the third one the same:

```
from itertools import product

for index1, index2 in product(range(3), range(2)):
    print(lst[index1][index2][0])
```

However I want to make this more general without knowing in advance how many substructures deep this needs to go (I want to make the number of `range`s passed to `itertools.product` variable).

I'm struggling a bit how I can generalize the `[index1][index2][0]` to accept an arbitary number of `indices`, the best I could come up with was `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

for indices in product(range(3), range(2)):
    print(reduce(list.__getitem__, indices, lst)[0])
```

That seems awfully complicated (and is significantly slower than the manual indexing), so I was wondering if there was a better and faster way to do that. I'm using both python 2.x and 3.x and external libraries are definetly okay (however it shouldn't require `NumPy` or packages based on `NumPy`).

Comment: By your statement *"However I want to make this more general without knowing in advance how many substructures deep this needs to go."* do you mean the depth of list is unknown i.e it could be n level deep/nested?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, the variable part is the **number** (`n`) of `ranges` given to `product` (and thus the length of `indices`). The depth of the list is "unknown" but at least `n+1` substructures deep. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use the python-builtin [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for this, and it doesn’t seem that complex and it wasn’t that much slower in my testing:

```
from itertools import product

for x in product(range(3), range(2)):
    rg = reduce(lambda result, index: result[index], x, lst)
    value = rg[0]
```

If you're worried about the timing penalty from `reduce`, you can just use a `for` loop instead:

```
for x in product(range(3), range(2)):
    value = lst
    for index in x:
        value = value[index]
    value = value[0]
```

This will, in all cases, be slower than manual indexing because a `for` loop will require extra operations for figuring out the stop condition.  The question, as always, is whether the speed optimization is worth it to you for the flexibility of arbitrary depth specification.

As for why you would use `reduce` vs. `for`, there is an ongoing stylistic debate within the JavaScript community as to whether you should use the `reduce`, `map`, `filter` functions on `Array`s or do the `for` loop version instead because it is faster, and you may want to refer to that debate to pick which side you fall on.

---

Timing with for loop:

```
In [22]: stmt = '''
    ...: from itertools import product
    ...: def go():
    ...:   lst = [[[1], [2]], [[3, 3], [4]], [[5], [6,6,6]]]
    ...:   for x in product(range(3), range(2)):
    ...:     # rg = reduce(lambda result, index: result[index], x, lst)
    ...:     value = lst
    ...:     for index in x:
    ...:         value = value[index]
    ...:     value = value[0]
    ...:     # value = lst[x[0]][x[1]][0]
    ...: '''

In [23]: timeit(setup=stmt, stmt='go()', number=1000000)
Out[23]: 4.003296852111816
```

Timing with `reduce`:

```
In [18]: stmt = '''
    ...: from itertools import product
    ...: def go():
    ...:   lst = [[[1], [2]], [[3, 3], [4]], [[5], [6,6,6]]]
    ...:   for x in product(range(3), range(2)):
    ...:     rg = reduce(lambda result, index: result[index], x, lst)
    ...:     value = rg[0]
    ...:     # value = lst[x[0]][x[1]][0]
    ...: '''

In [19]: timeit(setup=stmt, stmt='go()', number=1000000)
Out[19]: 6.164631128311157
```

Timing with manual indexing:

```
In [16]: stmt = '''
    ...: from itertools import product
    ...: def go():
    ...:   lst = [[[1], [2]], [[3, 3], [4]], [[5], [6,6,6]]]
    ...:   for x in product(range(3), range(2)):
    ...:     # rg = reduce(lambda result, index: result[index], x, lst)
    ...:     value = lst[x[0]][x[1]][0]
    ...: '''

In [17]: timeit(setup=stmt, stmt='go()', number=1000000)
Out[17]: 3.633723020553589
```

Comment: The `for`-loop seems to be the fastest and most-straightforward approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I propose a recursive way.

```
def theshape(lst):
    l=lst
    shape=[]
    while isinstance(l,list):
                shape.append(len(l))
                l=l[0]
    return shape
```

This function is intended to find the shape of your structure, which is supposed regular until last dimension.

```
def browse(lst):
    shape=theshape(lst)
    ndim=len(shape)
    def level(l,k):
        if k==ndim:
            print(l)
        else:
            for i in range(shape[k]):
                level(l[i],k+1)
    level(lst,0)
```

This one browse recursively all the levels. it minimize pointer changes.

A simple example :

```
u=arange(2**6).reshape(4,2,1,2,2,1,1,2).tolist()
browse(u)
0
2
.
.
.
62
```

Some tests on big structures (with print discarded by `print = lambda _ : None`) :

```
def go(lst):
 for x in product(*[range(k) for k in theshape(lst)]):
    print(reduce(lambda result, index: result[index], x, lst))

In [1]: u=arange(2**21).reshape([2]*21).tolist()

In [2]: %time go(u)
Wall time: 14.8 s

In [3]: %time browse(u)
Wall time: 3.5 s

In [5]: u=arange(2**21).reshape([1]*30+[2**21]+[1]).tolist()

In [6]: %time go(u)
Wall time: 18 s

In [7]: %time browse(u)
Wall time: 3.48 s

In [8]: u=arange(2**21).reshape([1]+[2**21]+[1]*30).tolist()

In [9]: %time go(u)
Wall time: 14 s

In [10]: %time browse(u)
Wall time: 58.1 s
```

This shows that performance is very data-structure dependent.

**EDIT:**

Finally, simplest is fastest. `theshape` is not necessary.

```
def browse2(lst):
        if isinstance(lst,list):
            for l in lst:
                browse2(l)
        else: print(lst)
```

it is often 30% faster than browse. And it works whatever the structure of the list.

Comment: wow that's confusing, I like the approach but lines like `shape=shape(lst)` seem totally weird :-) I'll check later if the approach works like I intended.

Comment: I add a new simplest version.

Comment: Actually I missed it earlier but this accesses the deepest nested `[0]` element, I actually want to access the `[0]` element at a fixed nesting and with pre-determined "ranges". The input is not always "regularly shaped" so the recursive approach has its disadvantages. I hope you don't mind that I accepted the (faster) other answer that directly solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

how about dynamically creating the hard indexing?

```
lst = [[[1], [2]], [[3, 3], [4]], [[5], [6,6,6]]]

from itertools import product

for index1, index2 in product(range(3), range(2)):
    print(lst[index1][index2][0])


# need depth info from somewhere to create hard coded indexing

prod_gen = product(range(3), range(2))

first = next(prod_gen)

indx_depth = len(first) + 1

exec( ('def IndexThisList(lst, indxl):\n' +
       '        return lst' + ''.join(('[indxl[' + str(i) + ']]' 
                                           for i in range(indx_depth)))))

# just to see what it exec'd:
print(("def IndexThisList(lst, indx_itrbl):\n" +
       "        return lst" + ''.join(('[indx_itrbl[' + str(i) + ']]' 
                                       for i in range(indx_depth)))))
# the exec is only invoked again when changing the indexing depth
# for accessing the list with its currently instantiated depth of indexing
# just use the current instance of the generated function

print(IndexThisList(lst, first + (0,)))
for itpl in prod_gen: 
    print (IndexThisList(lst, itpl + (0,)))

1
2
3
4
5
6
def IndexThisList(lst, indx_itrbl):
        return lst[indx_itrbl[0]][indx_itrbl[1]][indx_itrbl[2]]
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

just a beginner at this, seems like my exec should be wrapped with another function to pass the index_depth but its eluding me for now

Comment: why? when your own code is the only thing providing the code string there's no security issue

Comment: Mostly because it's a hassle to set them up correctly - and worse they are really hard to maintain.

Comment: "Fastest" isn't always most elegant, really needs to be raced with timeit

Comment: I've timed it and the `exec` seems to be a bottleneck, it takes roughly 100us to execute the `exec` which is already more than the other functions take for moderatly sized inputs. The function is also slower than a `for`-loop (independant of the `exec`-timings), probably because of the function call overhead.